# Postgres: Merge records with same ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a below PG table, say:

```
id  | type
----+------
001 | A
001 | B
002 | C
002 | B
```

And I want to convert it into the table below:

```
id  | type
----+------
001 | A, B
002 | C, B
```

How can I do that? If there are possible duplicates to this question please link it as I was not able to frame the subject correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(type) AS types FROM table GROUP BY id ORDER BY id;
```